# What is a segmentation fault? And how can I fix it?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, segmentation-fault, c++98

After outputting a string e.g. 20.58, I try to convert it to a double using `boost::lexical_cast`. But the next line of code does not run, and my program ends and I get a segmentation fault.

```
{
    string temp = matches[1];
    int size = temp.find_first_of("<"); //number of chars until "<"
    temp.resize(size);
    cout << "Match: " << temp << "\n";
    Price[1] = boost::lexical_cast<double>(temp);
    cout << "Price: $" << Price[1] << '\n';
    //break;
}
```

The output:

```
Match: 20.96

RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault; real time: 860ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

I would prefer to use std:stod; but I am using netbeans on a Mac OSX 10.6.8, and I have found that C++11 is not supported.

Comment: What's `Price[1]`? Are you sure the index 1 is valid there?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

A segmentation fault is a possible consequence of an *undefined behaviour*.

On a *nix platform, when a program performs an unauthorized memory operation, like reading from or writing to memory it doesn't own, the system may send a `SIGSEGV` signal to this process, which kills it by default.

In most cases, a segmentation fault is the consequence of a bad memory management, like dereferencing a null or dangling pointer, reading/writing outside an array, *etc*.

In your case, the fault could be in the existance of `Price[1]`, or if it exists, an issue with `typeof(Price[0])::operator=(double)`. But we won't debug your code unless it is a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).